# Android SoundPool doesn't work - just deliver a click-sound

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

I have six buttons and want to play different .mp3-files based on clicks. I've implemented the onClick-method like this:

```
SoundPool sp = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

if(view = screamButton) {
     soundId = sp.load(getContext(), R.raw.scream, 1);
}
// Some else if - statements

sp.play(soundId, 5, 5, 0, 0, 1);
```

I also tried to create an AudioManager to set the volume, but that didn't change anything.

What can be wrong?

Hank

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem than you.

My solution was:

In OnCreate put this:

```
    //The 20 is the maximum let the audio reproduce at the same time 
    sp = new SoundPool(20, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    //volume control from the cellphone:
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    //load the audio
    soundId= sp.load(this,R.raw.scream,1);
```

And, to last, when you want to the sound reproduction put this:

```
     sp.play(soundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
```

It works ok to me.

I hope help you.

Regards, Piero.